# How to retain Index information when calculating euclidean distances in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

Hi I would like to calculate euclidean distances between all points with X,Y coordinates in a dataframe and return the ID(the index) of the closest point.

currently I am using this to create a distance matrix:

```
diatancematrix=squareform(pdist(group))    
df=pd.DataFrame(dists)
```

followed by this to return the minimum point:

```
closest=df.idxmin()
```

I dont seem to be able to retain the correct ID/index in the first step  as it seems to assign column and row numbers from 0 onwards instead of using the index. is there a way to keep the correct index here?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303323/distance-calculation-between-rows-in-pandas-dataframe-using-a-distance-matrix

Comment: I don't think its quite the same as I am not sure how to produce the matrix without loosing the individual ids for each point

Answer (score 0):

The distance matrix includes each point's distance to itself, which will always be zero.  Thus, you should expect each row to just see itself as its own minimum.

Comment: In the workflow I  replace the 0 values with NaN values to avoid this issue

Comment: Only danger there is if another row shares the same coordinates with the original point.  Creating a mask along the diagonal is probably the best.

Comment: I see your point but all the  points are unique so that shouldn't occur.