# Euclidean distance between a single point to multiple points in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, euclidean-distance

My data frame has 16 x and y coordinates for positions{x1,x2...x16,y1,y2...y16} continuous from 0 to 566(m). I want to calculate Euclidean distance between x1,y1 wrt the remaining 15 coordinates and get the overall average distance. I want to repeat the process for all the 16 coordinates in the data frame and get their average distances from the other points.

My Data frame

```
import pandas as pd

import plotly.express as px

sample = {'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
          'columns': ['X1',
          'X2',
          'X3',
          'X4',
          'X5',
          'X6',
          'X7',
          'X8',
           'X9',
           'X10',
           'X11',
           'X12',
           'X13',
           'X14',
           'X15',
          'X16',
           'Y1',
           'Y2',
          'Y3',
          'Y4',
           'Y5',
           'Y6',
           'Y7',
           'Y8',
           'Y9',
           'Y10',
           'Y11',
           'Y12',
           'Y13',
           'Y14',
           'Y15',
          'Y16'],
          'data': [[500.4677, 278.6497, 47.4062, 417.3653, 551.7083, 401.1797, 0.0, 161.7773, 368.1543, 45.985, 520.4714, 566.0, 219.715, 45.0157, 284.9714, 202.886, 26.0476, 566.0, 0.0, 104.1045, 0.0, 335.7074, 486.5247, 566.0, 566.0, 258.2014, 376.2201, 477.4717, 412.28, 96.7684, 90.1294, 364.7503], 
          [511.751, 104.4383, 566.0, 380.4079, 345.8587, 0.0, 90.5588, 7.2899, 566.0, 566.0, 566.0, 313.0356, 191.8169, 200.6335, 566.0, 383.5991, 566.0, 135.7882, 463.57800000000003, 366.7474, 447.0349, 0.0, 410.16, 246.4883, 0.0, 208.0817, 60.8637, 566.0, 48.4488, 117.445, 411.2962, 566.0], 
         [19.699, 216.4378, 355.296, 67.8151, 518.7256, 72.1572, 222.7933, 223.9242, 566.0, 312.4474, 511.7909, 566.0, 78.0924, 226.1336, 566.0, 465.5424, 0.0, 566.0, 447.2046, 259.9073, 566.0, 320.6664, 418.3566, 351.0215, 354.9378, 566.0, 391.7332, 99.2301, 0.0, 137.3001, 535.2882, 566.0], 
         [0.0, 0.0, 243.342, 0.0, 566.0, 0.0, 198.4878, 0.0, 566.0, 566.0, 509.8984, 285.704, 144.3917, 294.7953, 399.9559, 345.9918, 380.3994, 462.8946, 566.0, 566.0, 0.0, 0.0, 234.3866, 53.6411, 546.4076, 253.0758, 0.0, 53.9287, 396.4652, 0.0, 0.0, 10.9969], 
         [446.6611, 421.0366, 493.1895, 566.0, 516.3773, 566.0, 566.0, 474.81699999999995, 566.0, 0.0, 299.7096, 30.5458, 0.0, 170.8087, 178.8432, 187.1938, 278.2215, 0.0, 551.9664, 566.0, 373.9421, 313.9131, 485.6295, 433.9819, 0.0, 481.3123, 0.0, 566.0, 0.0, 6.0358, 566.0, 465.4973], 
         [398.0662, 0.0, 172.95, 480.6902, 566.0, 566.0, 257.4459, 67.4326, 5.4764, 566.0, 0.0, 62.1571, 143.9684, 566.0, 236.2575, 341.5666, 102.6265, 484.4441, 7.9433, 0.0, 320.2722, 26.7175, 566.0, 540.0883, 349.5919, 213.1047, 0.0, 0.0, 566.0, 566.0, 503.7899, 116.725], 
         [113.7286, 341.2415, 418.0059, 0.0, 566.0, 566.0, 566.0, 0.0, 0.0, 566.0, 68.0914, 463.0868, 140.684, 18.4887, 220.1713, 273.2086, 566.0, 0.0, 270.9991, 503.3479, 0.0, 89.0062, 509.5509, 566.0, 287.7841, 566.0, 334.3373, 54.4844, 0.0, 206.8418, 396.798, 566.0], 
         [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 557.9507, 0.0, 566.0, 530.5327, 566.0, 461.61400000000003, 495.1422, 243.7463, 515.1805, 337.0039, 149.3637, 432.7603, 375.4085, 216.9741, 566.0, 424.6422, 405.3143, 323.5063, 160.0276, 0.0, 566.0, 566.0, 420.6266, 566.0, 566.0, 58.6311, 255.0382, 0.0, 566.0], 
         [369.2071, 304.0515, 566.0, 164.3125, 552.6091, 557.8421, 437.3143, 395.9587, 417.7882, 0.0, 0.0, 198.0035, 121.6725, 169.035, 225.88400000000001, 12.7346, 0.0, 476.0819, 0.0, 503.4461, 566.0, 447.1827, 53.9382, 566.0, 484.8547, 0.0, 566.0, 566.0, 566.0, 0.0, 362.2357, 269.9263], 
         [39.8478, 231.8411, 176.4778, 0.0, 566.0, 0.0, 566.0, 202.1302, 566.0, 291.1011, 0.0, 511.6552, 566.0, 113.6815, 566.0, 0.0, 512.7862, 177.8265, 85.63799999999999, 566.0, 0.0, 6.2889, 305.5369, 0.0, 566.0, 529.326, 136.871, 502.9318, 117.4366, 130.5829, 168.2698, 376.7318]]}



df = pd.DataFrame(index=sample['index'], columns=sample['columns'], 
data=sample['data'])
df
```

I have tried with below math formulae for all the coordinated individually and added all the distanced for the coordinate 1 to get the average distance for coordinate 1.

```
x1 = df.X1
x1 = df.X2
y1 = df.Y1
y2 = df.Y2

d12 = np.sqrt(np.square( x2 - x1 ) + np.square( y2 - y1 ))
avgd1 = (d12+d13+d14+d15+d16+d17+d18+d19+d110+d111+d112+d113+d114+d115+d116)/16.00
```

Similarly, I have taken average distances for all the 16 coordinates. But its not an efficient way and the code is getting very lengthy. Also my data set is very huge. So i want to know if there are any other efficient methods for my problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Distance calculation between rows in Pandas Dataframe using a distance matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303323/distance-calculation-between-rows-in-pandas-dataframe-using-a-distance-matrix)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to compute your distances in quite a concise way,
using *Numpy* functions and its **broadcasting** feature.

Define a function generating average distances for a row from your
source DataFrame:

```
def avgDist(row):
    xy = row.reshape(2, -1).T
    sqDist = ((xy[:, np.newaxis, :] - xy[np.newaxis, :, :]) ** 2).sum(axis=2)
    return np.sqrt(sqDist).sum(axis=1) / (row.size // 2 - 1)
```

The source *row* is a *1-D* *Numpy* array and the result is also
a *1-D* *Numpy* array.

Then, to generate the output DataFrame, run:

```
result = df.join(pd.DataFrame(np.apply_along_axis(avgDist, 1, df.values),
    columns=[ col.replace('X', 'avgd') for col in df.columns[:df.shape[1] // 2] ],
    index=df.index))
```

To test the above code, I prepared the following DataFrame:

```
       X1      X2     X15     X16      Y1      Y2     Y15     Y16
0    2.00    4.00    2.00    1.00    0.00    2.00    3.00    1.00
1  500.47  278.65  284.97  202.89   26.05  566.00   90.13  364.75
2  511.75  104.44  566.00  383.60  566.05  135.79  411.30  566.00
3   19.70  216.44  566.00  465.54    0.00  566.00  535.29  566.00
4    0.00    0.00  399.96  345.99  380.40  462.89    0.00   11.00
5  446.66  421.04  178.84  187.19  278.22    0.00  566.00  465.50
```

based on your picture (4 columns instead of 16), with an extra (first) row,
with points so located that is is easy to verify the results.

The result is:

```
       X1      X2     X15     X16      Y1      Y2     Y15     Y16       avgd1       avgd2      avgd15      avgd16
0    2.00    4.00    2.00    1.00    0.00    2.00    3.00    1.00    2.414214    2.742258    2.490712    2.270853 
1  500.47  278.65  284.97  202.89   26.05  566.00   90.13  364.75  419.806664  424.895850  329.120455  317.505970 
2  511.75  104.44  566.00  383.60  566.05  135.79  411.30  566.00  294.869112  547.618066  313.562415  293.388341 
3   19.70  216.44  566.00  465.54    0.00  566.00  535.29  566.00  694.854626  399.741581  406.931584  358.218465 
4    0.00    0.00  399.96  345.99  380.40  462.89    0.00   11.00  380.196350  421.123916  406.266123  376.780534 
5  446.66  421.04  178.84  187.19  278.22    0.00  566.00  465.50  330.838905  471.992748  369.870561  313.927197
```

Details how this code works:

1. Take the first row from the source DataFrame, as a *Numpy* array:

   ```
    row = df.values[0]
   ```

   The result is: `array([2., 4., 2., 1., 0., 2., 3., 1.])`.
2. Generate the first row of the above result, running `avgDist(row)`.
   The result is `array([2.41421356, 2.74225759, 2.49071198, 2.27085307])`.
3. *np.apply_along_axis* calls *avgDist* on each row of your source
   DataFrame (converted to a *Numpy* array) and concatenates
   results as consecutive rows of the output, also as a *Numpy* array.
4. *columns=[...]* convert column names from the first half of *df* ("X..."
   columns), replacing "X" with "avgd".
5. The argument of *join* is a DataFrame, with columns generated as above
   and the original index.
6. The last step is to join both DataFrames (on the index).

The "deeper level" of details - how *avgDist* works:

1. `xy = ...` - take the source row and transform it into a 2-column
   array. The first column contains *x* coordinates, and the second - *y*.

   For the first row of *df* the result is:

   ```
    array([[2., 0.],
           [4., 2.],
           [2., 3.],
           [1., 1.]])
   ```
2. `xy[:, np.newaxis, :] - xy[np.newaxis, :, :]` computes differences in
   each coordinate between every pair of points. The result is:

   ```
    array([[[ 0.,  0.],
            [-2., -2.],
            [ 0., -3.],
            [ 1., -1.]],

           [[ 2.,  2.],
            [ 0.,  0.],
            [ 2., -1.],
            [ 3.,  1.]],

           [[ 0.,  3.],
            [-2.,  1.],
            [ 0.,  0.],
            [ 1.,  2.]],

           [[-1.,  1.],
            [-3., -1.],
            [-1., -2.],
            [ 0.,  0.]]])
   ```
3. `sqDist = ((...) ** 2).sum(axis=2)` computes squares of these differences
   and sums them for each "point to point" pair. The result is:

   ```
    array([[ 0.,  8.,  9.,  2.],
           [ 8.,  0.,  5., 10.],
           [ 9.,  5.,  0.,  5.],
           [ 2., 10.,  5.,  0.]])
   ```

   No surprise, the diagonal contains zeroes, as they are distances from
   a point to just the same point.
4. The returned array is a sum of the above array, for each row, divided
   by the number of points - 1.

Maybe you should also search the Web for examples of how to use
*np.newaxis* to perform "each with each" computation on a sequence
of objects (in this case such an object is a row of *xy* array,
representing a point.